# Python: write a list with non-ASCII characters to a text file

Tags: python, list, file, ascii, newline

I'm using python 3.4 and I'm trying to write a list of names to a text file. The list is as follows:

```
my_list = ['Dejan Živković','Gregg Berhalter','James Stevens','Mike Windischmann',
               'Gunnar Heiðar Þorvaldsson']
```

I use the following code to export the list:

```
file = open("/Users/.../Desktop/Name_Python.txt", "w")
file.writelines( "%s\n" % item for item in my_list )
file.close()
```

But it does not work. Python seems not to like non-ASCII characters and gives me the following errors:

```
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u017d' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

Do you know if there is a way to solve this problem ? Maybe it's possible to write files in UTF-8 / unicode ?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: It works. 
I am not getting any error in python 2.7.6.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4, does the problem come from that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is that the file is getting openned with `ascii` encoding (which might be what is returned by [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) for your environment). You can try openning with the correct encoding (maybe `utf-8`) . Also, you should use `with` statement so that it handles closing the file for you.

For Python 2.x , you can use [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) function instead of `open()` -

```
with codecs.open("/Users/.../Desktop/Name_Python.txt", "w",encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.writelines( "%s\n" % item for item in my_list )
```

For Python 3.x , you can use the built-in function [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) , which supports `encoding` argument. Example -

```
with open("/Users/.../Desktop/Name_Python.txt", "w",encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.writelines( "%s\n" % item for item in my_list )
```

Comment: Worked for me too, I had trouble with this for a long time!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
>>> my_list = ['Dejan Živković','Gregg Berhalter','James Stevens','Mike Windischmann' ,'Gunnar Heiðar Þorvaldsson']
>>> f = open("/Users/.../Desktop/Name_Python.txt", "w")
>>> for x in my_list:
...     f.write("{}\n".format(x))
... 
>>> f.close()
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. I use Python 3 by the way, maybe the problem comes from that ?

Comment: @BernEy, i checked, its working with python3, does ur console support uft-8

Answer (score -1):

Try using UTF-8 encoding. You can start by putting # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top of your .py file.

Comment: if this were the problem, the file wouldn't even parse