# Python: how to parse non-ASCII characters in string

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, python-unicode

In my Python script, I'm trying to read in a text file that contains columns with people's first and last names, some of which have non-ASCII characters like `ñ`. But when I do so, I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 66`.

From what I've been reading online, I know you can handle this problem by ignoring or dropping the non-ASCII characters, but I don't want to do that. Is there a straight-forward way of converting all non-ASCII characters in a file into a normal string?

Currently, I'm opening my file with `infile = open(filename, 'rU')`.

**Not duplicate question**: I'm asking about how to *read* in a file with unicode characters, not how to write unicode string out to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: write a list with non-ASCII characters to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255846/python-write-a-list-with-non-ascii-characters-to-a-text-file)

Comment: The file was written on a MacOS

Comment: open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8')

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a copy of the file.
2. Make sure that your file in unicode and find out which unicode format it uses. some simple editors like [geany](https://geany.org) helps you to find the right encoding that was used on creation of the file. Split file if it is big and process a part of it by editors.
3. Use the correct encoding (maybe it is old cp encoding) for opening the file and do file conversion to utf8. Or use a tool (like editor) to convert it to utf8